# Swift 4: help decoding a JSON that contains an encoded image using base64

Tags: json, base64, swift4, xcode9

I'm a Swift (and programming) newb, fair warning.

I'm working on an app that is used to track scavenger hunt bonuses. I want to use a JSON file to contain all the bonus data, including a sample image. I see how to encode the image into base64 outside the program, then I can add it into my JSON as a string. Where I'm not certain is what to do with this? From searching I see you would use something like:

```
class func convertBase64ToImage(imageString: String) -> UIImage {
    let imageData = Data(base64Encoded: imageString, options: Data.Base64DecodingOptions.ignoreUnknownCharacters)!
    return UIImage(data: imageData)!
}
```

But I'm not certain if that would simply display said image, or if I need to save that and then call it somehow. The goal is to simply view the image (it is used for reference by the person taking a picture with their placard in the shot).

(I haven't implemented this in code yet, I'm still researching how to do it)

Comment: Any particular reason why do you want to encode it and decoded ?
- Going to upload it to a cloud service ?
- Want to save it on disk ?

Comment: The final intent is to keep the JSON on a server, and have the app check daily to see if the version of the JSON has increased, and if so, redownload it. This way the app can function without any data connection. The image in question is a sample image, so we would want to include that as part of the JSON being downloaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works fine. You can test it out in a Playground easily enough. I used https://www.base64-image.de to Base64 encode a small PNG file and generate a string which I ran through your function. It worked fine.

To answer your direct question, `UIImage` is simply an image which you can display to the user as follows:

Create a view controller. Add a `UIImageView` to the view controller and wire up an outlet for it with a suitable name (for example, `bonusImageView`).

Call your function within the view controller to load the image into the image view.

```
bonusImageView.image = convertBase64ToImage(imageString: imageString)
```

Where `imageString` is the Base64-encoded string you obtained from your JSON.

Whether or not you choose to store the `imageString` first is up to you. It's not necessary to store it if all you want to do is retrieve it from a server and display it on demand.

Comment: The app displays a sample image, which will be encoded in the JSON, and then separately has the ability to store the image taken by the user, which would become the thumbnail in my UITableView. It sounds like what you said about calling the function from my view controller will work, since this is a separate section they can view the sample image at, separate from the other image logic. I'll get to trying this out tonight and see what happens. Thank you for the info.